# Find which commit is currently checked out in Git

Tags: git

I'm in the middle of a `git bisect` session.

What's the command to find out which commit (SHA1 hash) I am currently on? `git status` does not provide this.

Edit: I guess calling `git log` and looking at first entry works?

Answer (score 285, accepted):

You have at least 5 different ways to view the commit you currently have checked out into your working copy during a `git bisect` session (**note that options 1-4 will also work when you're not doing a bisect**):

1. `git show`.
2. `git log -1`.
3. Bash prompt.
4. `git status`.
5. `git bisect visualize`.

I'll explain each option in detail below.

#### Option 1: git show

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168141/git-which-commit-am-i-on-have-checked-out/11168148#11168148) to the general question of how to determine which commit you currently have checked-out (not just during `git bisect`), you can use `git show` with the `-s` option to suppress patch output:

```
$ git show --oneline -s
a9874fd Merge branch 'epic-feature'
```

#### Option 2: git log -1

You can also simply do `git log -1` to find out which commit you're currently on.

```
$ git log -1 --oneline
c1abcde Add feature-003
```

#### Option 3: Bash prompt

In Git version 1.8.3+ (or was it an earlier version?), if you have your Bash prompt configured to show the current branch you have checked out into your working copy, then it will also show you the current commit you have checked out during a bisect session or when you're in a "detached HEAD" state. In the example below, I currently have `c1abcde` checked out:

```
# Prompt during a bisect
user ~ (c1abcde...)|BISECTING $

# Prompt at detached HEAD state 
user ~ (c1abcde...) $
```

#### Option 4: git status

Also as of Git version 1.8.3+ (and possibly earlier, again not sure), running `git status` will also show you what commit you have checked out during a bisect and when you're in detached HEAD state:

```
$ git status
# HEAD detached at c1abcde <== RIGHT HERE
```

#### Option 5: git bisect visualize

Finally, while you're doing a `git bisect`, you can also simply use [`git bisect visualize`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html#_bisect_visualize) or its built-in alias `git bisect view` to launch `gitk`, so that you can graphically view which commit you are on, as well as which commits you have marked as bad and good so far. I'm pretty sure this existed well before version 1.8.3, I'm just not sure in which version it was introduced:

```bash
git bisect visualize 
git bisect view # shorter, means same thing
```

[image]

Comment: Neat. When i asked the question i was not on Git 1.8, and since then I have gotten myself a zsh right-prompt which shows the commit hash, I think it might even show a special indicator specifically for if I am bisecting, but I haven't actually done any more bisecting since the time I asked this question, mostly `git log -p -S <search>` does the job.

Comment: `git status` doesn't show you the commit id unless you are in detached state. otherwise it says "On branch *whatever*". `git show` works though

Comment: I got three commits on the main branch and checked out the first commit using `git checkout <hash code> . ` but regardless of which command from this answer I run, it informs me that I am at the third commit. Am I missing something.

Answer (score 119):

You can just do:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

To explain a bit further: `git rev-parse` is git's basic command for interpreting [any of the exotic ways that you can specify the name of a commit](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_revisions) and `HEAD` is a reference to your current commit or branch.  (In a `git bisect` session, it points directly to a commit ("detached HEAD") rather than a branch.)

Alternatively (and easier to remember) would be to just do:

```
git show
```

... which defaults to showing the commit that `HEAD` points to.  For a more concise version, you can do:

```
$ git show --oneline -s
c0235b7 Autorotate uploaded images based on EXIF orientation
```

Comment: If you want to just get the hash for use elsewhere, `git rev-parse HEAD` requires no processing vs. all the garbage alternatives.

Comment: `git rev-parse --short HEAD` (shortens the object name to a unique prefix)

Answer (score 30):

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
273cf91b4057366a560b9ddcee8fe58d4c21e6cb
```

Update:

Alternatively (if you have tags):

(Good for naming a version, not very good for passing back to git.)

```
$ git describe
v0.1.49-localhost-ag-1-g273cf91
```

Or (as Mark suggested, listing here for completeness):

```
$ git show --oneline -s
c0235b7 Autorotate uploaded images based on EXIF orientation
```

Comment: You asked for a SHA1, not for something that is easy to remember. ;-)

Comment: This versione is very useful if you want to do some check in a script

Answer (score 21):

If you want to extract just a simple piece of information, you can get that using `git show` with the `--format=<string>` option...and ask it not to give you the diff with `--no-patch`.  This means you can get a printf-style output of whatever you want, which might often be a single field.

For instance, to get just the shortened hash (`%h`) you could say:

```
$ git show --format="%h" --no-patch
4b703eb
```

If you're looking to save that into an environment variable in bash (a likely thing for people to want to do) you can use the [`$()` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4651495/211160):

```
$ GIT_COMMIT="$(git show --format="%h" --no-patch)"

$ echo $GIT_COMMIT
4b703eb
```

The full [list of what you can do is in `git show --help`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show).  But here's an abbreviated list of properties that might be useful:

- `%H` commit hash
- `%h` abbreviated commit hash
- `%T` tree hash
- `%t` abbreviated tree hash
- `%P` parent hashes
- `%p` abbreviated parent hashes
- `%an` author name
- `%ae` author email
- `%at` author date, UNIX timestamp
- `%aI` author date, strict ISO 8601 format
- `%cn` committer name
- `%ce` committer email
- `%ct` committer date, UNIX timestamp
- `%cI` committer date, strict ISO 8601 format
- `%s` subject
- `%f` sanitized subject line, suitable for a filename
- `%gD` reflog selector, e.g., refs/stash@{1}
- `%gd` shortened reflog selector, e.g., stash@{1}

Comment: All those formatting options, but `show` has nothing for _branch_.

Answer (score 4):

Use `git show`, which also shows you the commit message, and defaults to the current commit when given no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you do use `git bisect visualize`, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18160212/6309); make sure to use Git 2.42 (Q3 2023).

"[`git bisect visualize`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8cdd5e713d7ba54b9d26ac997408bb745ab55088/Documentation/git-bisect.txt) "<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect))</sup> stopped running `gitk` on Git for Windows when the command was reimplemented in C around Git 2.34 timeframe.
This has been corrected with Git 2.42 (Q3 2023).

See [commit fff1594](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fff1594fa77372ea7a51f6b445267f23fdbf3089), [commit 2bf46a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2bf46a9f62159ced3a84ab8bc9ba151778414bd6), [commit bb532b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb532b534547d0a6b203baaf2f3379d987f611b9) (04 Aug 2023) by [Matthias Aßhauer (`rimrul`)](https://github.com/rimrul).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8cdd5e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8cdd5e713d7ba54b9d26ac997408bb745ab55088), 09 Aug 2023)</sup>

> ### [`compat/mingw`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2bf46a9f62159ced3a84ab8bc9ba151778414bd6): implement a native `locate_in_PATH()`
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Louis Strous</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Matthias Aßhauer</sup>

> since [5e1f28d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e1f28d20600ea7d482db875cbd759b410c095b7) (`bisect--helper`: reimplement `bisect_visualize()` shell function in C, 2021-09-13, Git v2.34.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0a4cb1f1f2f64e5f3791809284ba786a8094dfb4) listed in [batch #8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ddb1055343948e0d0bc81f8d20245f1ada6430a0)) (bisect--helper: reimplement `bisect_visualize()` shell function in C, 2021-09-13) [`git bisect`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2bf46a9f62159ced3a84ab8bc9ba151778414bd6/Documentation/git-bisect.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect))</sup> visualize uses `exists_in_PATH()`> to check wether it should call `gitk`, but `exists_in_PATH()` relies on `locate_in_PATH()` which currently only understands POSIX-ish PATH variables (a list of paths, separated by colons) on native Windows executables we encounter Windows PATH variables (a list of paths that often contain drive letters (and thus colons), separated by semicolons).
> Luckily we do already have a function that can lookup executables on windows PATHs: `path_lookup()`.

And:

> ### [`docs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fff1594fa77372ea7a51f6b445267f23fdbf3089): update when `git bisect visualize` uses `gitk`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Matthias Aßhauer</sup>

> This check has involved more environment variables than just `DISPLAY` since [508e84a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/508e84a790bef46881459891748727c490d9a673) ("bisect view: check for MinGW32 and MacOSX in addition to X11", 2008-02-14, Git v1.5.5-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/508e84a790bef46881459891748727c490d9a673)), so let's update the documentation accordingly.

`git bisect` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fff1594fa77372ea7a51f6b445267f23fdbf3089/Documentation/git-bisect.txt#L207-L214):

> Git detects a graphical environment through various environment variables:
> `DISPLAY`, which is set in X Window System environments on Unix systems.
> `SESSIONNAME`, which is set under Cygwin in interactive desktop sessions.
> `MSYSTEM`, which is set under Msys2 and Git for Windows.
> `SECURITYSESSIONID`, which may be set on macOS in interactive desktop sessions.
>
> If none of these environment variables is set, 'git log' is used instead.
> You can also give command-line options such as `-p` and `--stat`.
> Implement a small replacement for the existing `locate_in_PATH()` based on `path_lookup()`.