# Generating Info File on Compilation

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, qmake

I am trying to get my project generates a file with relevant compile data (compiler version, lib version, date, git commit, etc). So my question is how do I make this run only at compile time, when it will have access to the needed information?

Comment: Mentioning what build system you are using may be useful when asking about how to make a build system do something.  I could guess qmake?

Comment: what you want is a log of the compile process, that, if available, should be a configuration on your compiler...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the compilation log? If it doesn't provide enough information, you can create a script that gathers the data and print it to a file.

- Compiler version:

  - For Visual Studio, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1233332/1485885).
  - If your compiler is gcc use `gcc --version`.
- Current git commit can be obtained by any of the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18160212/1485885).
- Library versions will depend on each particular case: maybe the compilation log have that data for some of them, print the library path (sometimes such directories contain the version number, at least for some libraries), etc.
- Current date/time:

  - bash: `date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S`
  - Windows' command line, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/203116/1485885).

Finally, the script can be invoked as the last step in your makefile or as a [post-build event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7dhf0ty.aspx) in the case of a Visual Studio project.